# In LyX, how do I indent the paragraph right after an lists (itemize/enumerate) environment

Tags: lyx, lists, indentation, itemize

[image]

See the example above, I want to indent the second paragraph.

The generated .tex file is

```
%% LyX 2.0.4 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
First paragraph.
\begin{itemize}
\item item 1
\item item 2
\end{itemize}
Second paragraph.

Third paragraph.
\end{document}
```

Simply add a blank line after the line `\end{itemize}` will do what I want. But how can I do this in LyX?

One possible way is to add a box of TeX code (Evil Red Text) containing one blank line before second paragraph. But I want to know if there are ways without invoving Evil Red Text. Thanks.

Comment: add a blank line after the `\end{itemize}`

Comment: @Seamus I know I can simply add a blank line in the generated .tex file, but this is a question about LyX and I'm seeking a direct and elegant solution within LyX.

Comment: Hmm, moving the cursor to the start of the second paragraph and hitting enter doesn't work, it just jumps back when you move the cursor again. Might be a bug in LyX. In any case that behavior seems silly.

Comment: Hope this work. I just add a "separator". You click in the scroll bar under File and Edit Menu... Another thing is, you need to view always the source code/tex code for you to be able to know that you  are in the next paragraph.

Comment: @TianyiCui There's nothing direct or elegant about LyX. Why not just join the dark side and write directly in LaTeX? With editors like TeXshop or Gummi you can get auto-updating output anyway, so why stick with LyX's awkward restrictions?

Comment: @jee-ar I didn't find where to add the "separator" you mentioned, could you specify it more? Thanks.

Comment: @Seamus Thanks for noticing. Maybe I'll give TeXshop or Gummi a try later.

Comment: @TianyiCui The Separator environment is found in the drop-down menu in the top left (the same list where you find Chapter, Section, etc.)

Comment: @TianyiCui: It can be found at the standard toolbar. Click Drop down list "Standard" then --Separator--.

Comment: Currently I'm using this solution: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7380b.png. Empty ERT in a blank paragraph, less intrusive and easier to type than ERT code.

Comment: @TianyiCui It's perfectly fine to answer ones own question (and accept that answer), so please turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works without any ERT. Redefine itemize environment as showed int the preamble of this MWE:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\let\olditemize\itemize
\renewenvironment{itemize}
{\begin{olditemize}}
{\par
\end{olditemize}
\vspace{0.7\baselineskip}
\par}

\begin{document}
First paragraph 
\begin{itemize}
\item item 1
\item item 2
\item item 3
\end{itemize}
First paragraph  

Third paragraph 
\end{document}
```

Change 0.7\baselineskip if you want more space after the last item.

Comment: The OP specifically asked if he could do this without an ERT. (And personally, I don't think `\setlength\parindent{0pt}` is a good idea, though it does at least hide the problem.)

Comment: Torbjørn, I agreed. Change \parident is not a good idea for any real article. Insert a ERT could be not elegant but it is less problematic.

Comment: Currently I'm using this solution: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7380b.png. Empty ERT in a blank paragraph, less intrusive and easier to type than ERT code.

Comment: I changed completely my answer because I have found the way to redefine itemize and this solve the problem without ERT.

Answer (score 2):

- Set the cursor at the end of the last item and choose `Edit -> Start New Environment (Itemize)` or in the context menu (right-click) ([works since LyX version 2.1](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/NewInLyX21#layouts)) or
- Insert a new item and change the text layout to `--Separator--` ([works since LyX version 1.6](http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/4993)).

The solution works for all lists environments (itemize, enumerate, description) and should work as well for all other environments.

Credits go to Günter Milde who [posted it in LyX users mailinglist](http://lyx.475766.n2.nabble.com/Blank-Line-Before-begin-itemize-in-Geneterated-LaTeX-tt481808.html#a481815).

Comment: In your first bullet point, does the user then need to change the layout from "itemize" (which is the result of "Start New Environment (Itemize)" to "Standard"?

Comment: @scottkosty You're right. I just tested it with an itemize where already a paragraph follows. Without a following paragraph, at the first option you need to delete the new item and type an Enter to get the standard layout. So, the second option would then be the easier option.

Answer (score 1):

to end items and go back to your normal paragraph press enter and you l be put in a new item righ? look up to the icon "implicite" next to "liste numeroté",, it looks like a paper with lines in it ,, press it and bamm ! problem solved.

Comment: Could you correct your grammar and punctuation to conform to English? It's not really clear what you mean as it stands.